# SQL Inner join where record does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have 2 tables that I'm querying using the INNER JOIN clause. My first table labeled departments is fairly simple, containing only 3 fields - deptID, deptName, and companyID. My second table labeled departmentMemberships is even simpler, containing only 2 field - deptID and employeeID. My current SQL statement queries both of these tables and returns all of the deptID's, deptName's and the number of employees in each department. My query will not return a department if there aren't any employees enlisted in the aforementioned department. This is my current query.

```
`SELECT departments.deptID, departments.deptName,
COUNT(departmentMemberships.deptID) AS employeeCount
FROM departmentMemberships
INNER JOIN departments
ON departmentMemberships.deptID = departments.deptID
WHERE departments.companyID = 1
GROUP BY departments.deptID, departments.deptName
ORDER BY departments.deptName ASC;`
```

Excuse my inexperience with TSQL, but how could I alter this query to return all departments, including the ones with no employees enrolled?

Thank you very much

Comment: To return rows/columns where join criteria doesn't exist, you need to use an `OUTER JOIN`, or UNION of whatever combination of queries gets the appropriate records with NULL placeholders.

Comment: visual explanation of joins http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written, change your `INNER JOIN` to a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.  But I prefer `LEFT JOIN` myself; it's easier to follow.  I.e.:

```
SELECT departments.deptID
     , departments.deptName
     , COUNT(departmentMemberships.deptID) AS employeeCount
FROM departments
LEFT OUTER JOIN departmentMemberships
ON departmentMemberships.deptID = departments.deptID
WHERE departments.companyID = 1
GROUP BY departments.deptID, departments.deptName
ORDER BY departments.deptName ASC
```